# Python doesn't work with heroku

Tags: python, heroku, dialogflow-es

I'm using api ai to make a weather bot and i'm making webhook. But it doesn't work with heroku.

Logs:

```
2017-02-12T01:04:09.580619+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-12T01:04:09.580628+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-02-12T01:04:09.431329+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f5b127a by user ntrung03@gmail.com
2017-02-12T01:04:09.431329+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user ntrung03@gmail.com
2017-02-12T01:04:09.768517+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user ntrung03@gmail.com
2017-02-12T01:04:55.382953+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-12T01:04:55.382960+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-02-12T01:04:55.273050+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f5b127a by user ntrung03@gmail.com
2017-02-12T01:04:55.273050+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user ntrung03@gmail.com
2017-02-12T01:04:55.517592+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user ntrung03@gmail.com
2017-02-12T01:05:02.283592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/webhook" host=botmia.herokuapp.com request_id=cf6fc4f6-fd84-415b-b2de-0c69e140ef5b fwd="54.198.43.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-12T01:08:56.636508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/webhook" host=botmia.herokuapp.com request_id=2e1b3ba4-c495-431e-8695-7dd742258201 fwd="54.198.43.155" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-12T01:12:28.027455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=botmia.herokuapp.com request_id=23238026-ba99-45da-a0d4-94b426e8dbb8 fwd="117.5.143.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-12T01:12:29.548164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=botmia.herokuapp.com request_id=95a8d5b9-639f-405e-a83e-a4603ab44f1c fwd="117.5.143.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

[Host on Heroku](https://botmia.herokuapp.com/)

[Source](https://github.com/TrungNguyen1909/BotMia)

[A similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360123/heroku-cannot-work-with-my-python-script)
But doesn't work
Thanks everyone by helping me. I'm new one to Api.ai heroku & python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error logs, it looks like you have a code `H14`, which means that you haven't started your web dynos (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running). You can start a dyno by running `heroku ps:scale web=1` from your terminal (assuming you have the heroku command line tools installed). You need to have at least 1 dyno running for your site to function.

I was able to get your app successfully running on a new heroku site with the following commands run in the app directory on my machine:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/TrungNguyen1909/BotMia
$ cd BotMia
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

After doing that, making a post request to `/webhook` successfully access that endpoint as you can see in the logs:

`2017-02-12T01:53:12.721050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=MY_HOST request_id=REQ_ID fwd="IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=452`

Answer (score 0):

For Heroku, you describe your dyno configuration in your `Procfile` which is supposed to live in the root of your project.

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile